# AddButton in NavigationBar on TabBarController and call Segue from ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, tabbarcontroller

i have a TabBarController with two ViewController. One of them has a TableView. I want to set in the NavigationBar of ViewController with have the TableView a BarButtonItem (Add), so that the BarButtonItem is only show when the TableView is in front. 
But it doesn't work. I never see the BarButtonItem.
So i put it on then TabBarController an i see it, but in both ViewController. That's not that what i want. 
An i can not call the segue, from the ViewController (TableView) to the DetailViewController, because my TabBarController not know it.

What is the right solution to do this? How can i put a BarButtonItem on then NavigationBar on a ViewController that ist Client of a TabBarController?

Thanks
PS: i coding in swift ;-)

Comment: set the initial view controller of storyboard as UiNavigationViewcontroller. I will help you to add bar button items..

Answer (score 0):

I post a Picture of my actual Storyboard, so you can understood me better.

["a picture of storyboard"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muPre.png)

When i place my add-button at position one i can't call the seque for a new Item in the data of the tableview.

When i place my add-button at position two i can call the segue, but i never see the button to click it.

my tabbarcontroller is showing when i clicked on detail for a cell on the tableview at the left on the picture.